# How to make a token "\" in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I want to make tokens for integer division and float division

For example :

```
DIV_F : '/';
DIV_I : '\'; // Error here
```

There is an error in second line :

```
" mismatched character 'EOF' expecting ''' "
```

So what should I do now ? Your help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a lot of languages, the backslash `\` is an escape character. So I think you may be escaping the closing single quote. Try

```
DIV_I : '\\';
```

to escape the backslash so that it knows you mean the literal character.

This [page](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules) may help.